# Unable to mouse hover in firefox using selenium

Tags: eclipse, firefox, mousehover

I'm using selenium version 2.47.1 and firefox version 40.
Code snippet:

`public void myMouseOver(WebElement we)
    {
        Actions a = new Actions(_driver);
        a.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
    }`

I'm unable to mouse hover the element by this way. But it is working fine with chrome. Is there any compatibility issue with the versions of selenium and firefox?

Comment: Selenium support firefox version 33 max. after that it does not support.

Comment: Is there any other way for performing mouse-hover using the same version of firefox? @HelpingHands

Comment: Use Firefox version 33 or previous..that is only way.